# Java generics on super class but not all subclasses want to define a type parameter

Tags: java

I didn't know how to title this very well... I'm hoping that the inspiration will come at a later date and I can update it, but...

Let me describe this with some (pseudo) code:

I am trying to handle AJAX requests on my server in a tidy way this is what I have come up with.

Base request:

```
public abstract class BaseRequest<T> {

    private final T details;

    public BaseRequest(T details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public abstract void process();

}
```

Then I have a request that handles some data coming in, lets say it is for a login request where `LoginDetails` is a bean:

```
public class LoginRequest extends BaseRequest<LoginDetails> {

    public LoginRequest(T details) {
        super(details);
    }

    /**
     * @Override
     */
    public void process() {
        Toolbox.login(this.details);
    }

}
```

This has worked well up til now... I have various requests where I bind form data to beans and pass them in to these requests using Futures. All is good... until...

I decide to make the logout request. This request requires no data to be bound to a bean and therefore I do not wish to define a type parameter (eeeek it's all gonna break). What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
public class LogoutRequest extends BaseRequest {

    public LogoutRequest() {
        super(null);
    }

    /**
     * @Override
     */
    public void process() {
        Toolbox.logout();
    }

}
```

And whilst this does compile and work it makes my skin crawl due to type safety.

Now... I know how to solve this but I was wondering if there was a better way.

**My solution**

Would be to have an untyped base request and a typed subclass of this that the data requests subclass and the logout request would just subclass the untyped base request.

Untyped base request:

```
public abstract class BaseRequest {

    public abstract void process();

}
```

Typed base data request:

```
public abstract class BaseDataRequest<T> extends BaseRequest {

    private final T details;

    public BaseDataRequest(T details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

}
```

Then login:

```
public class LoginRequest extends BaseDataRequest<LoginDetails> {

    public LoginRequest(T details) {
        super(details);
    }

    /**
     * @Override
     */
    public void process() {
        Toolbox.login(this.details);
    }

}
```

and logout:

```
public class LogoutRequest extends BaseRequest {

    /**
     * @Override
     */
    public void process() {
        Toolbox.logout();
    }

}
```

I just want to make sure that my solution is the best option and I haven't missed some way of specifying NULL type (i know this concept doesn't exist) or something mad like that. Could someone please confirm for me.

Also I'm taking suggestions for an updated title to the question.

Comment: Why are you even extending BaseRequest in LogoutRequest? With what you've shown, you have no need to extend BaseRequest at all. You're not using anything from it, other than the method, which could be put into an interface, call it RequestInterface.  Then your Request classes could implement this interface.  So you'd have BaseRequest<T> implements RequestInterface, LoginRequest extends BaseRequest<LoginDetails> implements RequestInterface, LogoutRequest implements RequestInterface, etc

Comment: The actual code is more complex than that and the base class has methods for constructing JSON responses in an organised way, as well as a few other things like handling errors etc... I didn't include that code however as it wasn't relevant to the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe just create a constructor that takes no parameter? and use this one for the LogoutRequest class?

Comment: Actually my code works and adding the no args constructor doesn't solve the type safety problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with thinking of some kind of null type.  Such a thing doesn't exist in Java, but Java does contain [the `Void` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html).

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

You can make the type parameter `Void`, so that only `null` can be passed in the call to the superclass constructor.

```
public class LogoutRequest extends BaseRequest<Void> {

    public LogoutRequest() {
        super(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew there would be some way out there that I had overlooked. That's the issue if you don't have the right keywords google will sometimes fail you :( anyway I have just added `<Void>` in to my code and all type safety concerns melted away and I didn't have to create new classes or refactor my code... I'm a happy bunny. Thank you, I'm glad I took the time to ask (I just learned something new for today)

Comment: Also this question just gave me 666 rep... should I be concerned?

Comment: I upvoted your question and you got to 666 (not that it matters; I didn't notice). Just accept the answer that you feel answers your question the best, and you'll be at 668!

Comment: Aye I will now... but it made me wait 5 mins. the Devil could have appeared at any time during that period. Btw he didn't show... phew!